# Django tables2 add custom column for another model

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I don't know if this question had been covered or not yet, I searched all the related questions but I couldn't find a solution.

What I want to do is to create a table using django-tables2 with a model let's say model A, and I want to add a custom column to this table having value from model B which is not related in any case to model A.

This is what I did

```
class TableA(tables.Table):
  
    class Meta:
        model = A
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("id","username","data_from_b")
```

Where can I put the `B.objects.filter()` to append it's data to a custom column.

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using a custom render method? https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods `def render_b_objs(): return B.objects.filter()`

Comment: @Ben thanks I managed to make it work using render. If you formulate your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom render method to retrieve anything you need.

https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods

For example, a list of B names could look like:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class TableA(tables.Table):

    data_from_b = tables.Column()

    class Meta:
        model = A
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("id","username","data_from_b")
    
    def render_data_from_b(self, value, record):
        return mark_safe("</br>".join(B.objects.filter().values_list("name", flat=True)))
```